# Open webarchive file in HTML

Tags: html, safari, webarchive

I am trying to open a web archive file via a html webpage, and the file just downloads instead of opening.

How can i get this to open as a webpage?

My code is;

```
<a class="view-product" href="Basket.webarchive" data-analytics-event="click" data-event-category="Search Listings" data-event-action="Product Click" data-event-label="View Product">Add to Basket</a>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

add this to the `<a >` :

```
target="_blank"
```